# The number of users authenticated under one account in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-session

I have ASP.NET MVC 3 application and wonder if it is possible to make unlimited access of users logged in using the same account? What is the maximum permitted number of such users? Taking into an account that users work in the app simultaneously. There are about 100 users were successfully logged in under the same userID, but if more users try, there will be error like bad login or password. How could it be?
I'd appreciate any answer.

Comment: If I understood it correct, you want to the maximum permitted number of logins with same user. If thats the case I dont think that there is any limit. It depends on the buisness requierment whehter you want to allow a user to login from multiple machines or browser instances.

Comment: Right, so there is unlimited number of sessions under one user? what could be the reason for an error?

Comment: I dont think the error has to do with the number of instances the user has logged in to the application. The Error says Bad login or password which means the credentials that are used might be wrong.